# Как запретить выключение экрана?

Tags: java, android

Если запустить приложение, то после определенного времени (это время устанавливается в настройках), экран выключается, кроме видео плеера. Как программно сделать такое в своем приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html), рекомендуется пользоваться следующими методиками:

- только для активити-класса:

  ```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  ```
- применительно к конкретному `view`:

  - `android:keepScreenOn="true"` в xml-разметке;
  - `view.setKeepScreenOn(true)` программно.

Comment: Уважаемый Serodv, огромное Вам спасибо! Все получилось!

Comment: @Serodv а что `WakeLock` не нужен разве?

Comment: WakeLock может быть альтернативой, но нежелательной - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602